# rails - reference error with using Foundation and Angular

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

My Rails application uses Angular JS, Foundation CSS framework
and their library reference order seems to cause browser console error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`.

When I installed Foundation it added `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` automatically and I wonder if I have to do the same for making Angular to work.
From one of the RailsCasts clip about Angular, it was recommended to opt out jquery as Angular already comes with most of jquery library but if I remove jquery from here, it complains about `undefined jquery`

This is my application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require foundation
//= require jquery

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

Comment: Try moving jquery above angular.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks. I tried this and many other different order but it seems to be something else.

Comment: I am pretty sure it will be ordering issue. If you have any angular code written already, `require_tree` must go last, and definitively after angular. Try `jquery`, `angular`, `angular-rsrc`, `foundationn`, `turbolinks`(do you really need it with angular :) ) and then `require_tree`